# Referencing fixture record in yii2/codeception data files

Tags: php, yii2, fixtures, codeception

Is there a way to specify a related row of another fixture in fixture data file in Yii2/Codeception ActiveFixture? Consider this example of user/profile relation:

user.php:

```
return [
    'user1' => [
        'email' => 'user1@example.net',
     ]
];
```

profile.php:

```
use common\models\User;
return [
    'profile1' => [
        'user_id' => User::findOne(['email' => 'user1@example.net'])->id;
        'name' => 'My Name',
     ]
];
```

The documentation states that "You may give an alias to a row so that later in your test, you may refer to the row via the alias." Is there a way to reference rows inside another fixture? For example, use something like $this->user('user1')->id in profile.php? I could not find any mention on how to do that. How do you create this kind of related fixtures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliased data can be accessed only inside scope of dedicated `Fixture` object through its `data` property after its `load()` method has been executed. The only way to make this data accessible from data file of another `Fixture` object is to register it with some global object, for example `Application` object.

I usually just query all needed data before constructing dependent dataset:

```php
use common\models\User;
$users = User::find()->indexBy('email')->all();
return [
    'profile1' => [
        'user_id' => $users['user1@example.net']->id,
        'name' => 'My Name',
     ]
];
```

Answer (score 4):

I use Faker with Yii2.
When I started to write test, I found out that I need good fixtures. 
In yii2 there is yii2-faker/FixtureController , that can generate fixtures.
[More in documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-faker-index.html)

But I get the same problem as author. I need to genereate fixtures for users, profiles(that contain user_id) and roles . I didn't found a solution in documentation, how to do it, but this work for me.

Templates:
users.php

```
return [
'id' => $index +1 ,
'login' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
'password' => $user->hashPassword('123qwe'),
'type' => '0',
'is_active' => '1',
'is_verified' => '1',
'created_at' => time(),
'updated_at' => time(),
```

];

profiles.php

```
return [
'id' => $index +1 ,
'user_id' => $index +1 ,
'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
'middle_name' => $faker->optional()->firstName,
'phone' => $faker->unique()->phoneNumber,
'contact_email' => $faker->email
```

];

The main feature here is - $index.

```
`$index`: the current fixture index. For example if user need to generate 3 fixtures for user table, it will be 0..2.
```

So I could know what id would be in user and insert it into profile.

After that I run the command:

```
php yii fixture/generate users profiles --count=100
```

And have generated 100 users with profiles.
I hope it helps some one.